# Making a mini pokemon project and I need unique classes?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at Java and i wanted to code a pokemon battle game. So my idea was that I can have a randomly generated team of pokemon for the user. These will be chosen at random in an array with a random number generator. Once they have been chosen a pokemon, it will then print out all the stats and possible evo's along with attributes etc. I need to make a pokemon abstract class in which I will have a bunch of subclasses that are pokemon. The problem I have is that I have nothing unique to put inside these subclasses as all the pokemon share the same "variables". I'm coding this for a school project that requires me to use abstract classes and polymorphism as such. Therefore, is there any unique that I can put into my subclasses?

Comment: I disagree that this question is too broad. The main issue is that it doesn't state the actual question which asks about the standards of object-oriented programming.

Comment: I'd imagine you could use subclasses that are unique. I only know a couple things about the Pokemon card game, one of them being that attacks are quite different. So that unique thing between Pokemon subclasses could be an abstract attack method where you may simulate coin flips or just compute damage based on some base elemental strength versus opponents elemental defense, or sometimes also taking into account how much health left the pokemon has (like lower health more damage dealt to the opponent).

Answer (score 2):

You've answered the question yourself: you have nothing to put into unique pokemon subclasses, so you don't need them. Instead, you could make constructors in a non-abstract pokemon class that create a pokemon object for a specific pokemon.

Example:

```
public class Pokemon {
    private String type;
    private String health;

    public Pokemon (String name) {
        if (name.equals("Pikachu")) {
            this.type = "electric";
            this.health = 80;
        } else if (name.equals("Charmander")) {
            this.type = "fire";
            this.health = 50;
        }
    }
    // More of your code
}
```

The key concept here is that things that have different functionality (aka new types of stats, new game mechanics) require new classes. Things that simply have different values for the functionality you already have (in an abstract class or otherwise) only need new INSTANCES of the class: new objects.